# Gmail API in a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth, gmail, google-api

I am trying to get Gmail updates in a chrome extension, other than oauth is there anything specific thing I need to do, to import the Gmail API into the extension?

Comment: That is not a specific thing that is the main idea, the essential thing for that project.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [complete](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html) code example from the most credible source.
You will also need to connect to Gmail with either the the [IMAP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) or SMTP protocol in order to check for new emails.

Answer (score -1):

There is a lot of documentation from Google on [how to implement OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) for your extension as well as how to [connect to Google Services](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?csw=1).

The documentation will tell you what kinds of permissions you'll need.

Comment: Curious about why the downvote? The answer to your question, including all APIs, permissions, and requirements for the app, is in the documentation.